# cron job on webserver

Tags: php, cron

the last days I have researched about cron jobs. First I want to tell you abaout my problem.
I want to run a php script on my webserver every minute without loading the page. this php script inserts some data via yql. I read that cron is just working with unix/linux. my server runs on unix (wait for it). is it now possible for me to let my script run while sleeping in bed (computer off) just by the server side? do I got this all right? if yes, I also have to know how the path have to be look like in my command part in my schedule, because every example contents something like "* */1 * * *  /usr/bin/wget http://www.example.com/cron.php", but why there is /usr/bin/wget in the path (that means, this cron is running just from my computer system not from the webserver) and how to put my schedule on the server and better where. my server have the root public_html where my index.php is inside. please give me an example of the schedule and how to fire my php data called "to_fire.php" that puts the data on my database via mysql.

I hope that some of you know what I exactly mean by own experience. im kinda confused by this command part and how to let it run from just the webserver and not my computer system.

thanks

Comment: On your server just set up set up cron as `*/1 * * * * cd /path/to/script; php some_script.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `wget` is a unix command to visit a web URL. `curl` is another command working similarly. You could also use `php path\to\script.php` to run, as Gigawatt mentioned. There is no big difference from all of them
2. `* */1 * * *` is to set cron timing.
3. `/usr/bin/wget` is the location where `wget` on your server
4. Yes, once cron set, you can leave it alone. As long as server is living, the cron will run as scheduled. You can even set cron to send you an email, but that's no applicable to your case as running per min is to short.
5. Running cron per min seems not common. If you are doing something like realtime update, consider other solution.
6. Cron can be set on cPanel.
7. You need to config your cron script to accept request from same server only, to avoid others access this URL.

#### Some resource for cron

Configuring cron jobs in cPanel http://drupal.org/node/369267

Backup Databases using a cron http://wiki.lunarpages.com/Backup_Databases_using_a_cron

Configuring cron jobs using the cron command http://drupal.org/node/23714

Managing Cron Jobs with PHP http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Comment: thank you guys. now i just have to know how to get into the root server and type my schedule inside. im not good with Unix/Linux. other ressources telling me to connect to the web servers shell acount? do you know an easy way to get my schedule (crontab) there?

Comment: @user1791283, the easiest way is to set it in cPanel, as the first resource mentioned. You don't need to know linux well, just need to know how to write the script, then you schedule it in cpanel.